# Как получить вычисления в Delphi с точностью программы Mathematica

Tags: delphi, mathematica

Возможно ли использовать каким-либо образом одну из библиотек Mathtematica в *Delphi*, Или обеспечить каким-либо другим образом такую точность?

Дело в том, что меня попросили сделать оболочку для программы расчета *Mathtematica* и реализовать некоторые ее расчеты в *Delphi*, что я и сделал, но в расчетах *Mathtematica*, используется высокая точность, до 18-20 знаков после запятой... Которую к сожалению *Delphi* не может обеспечить (даже типом «extended»), или может, НО проблема с точностью 18 знака после запятой (они при некоторых расчетах отличаются).
Я уже попробовал 5 библиотек сторонних производителей (производящие расчеты такой точности), но не одна полностью НЕ подошла.
На одном из сайтов узнал, что WL использует высоко-оптимизированные библиотеки типа *Intel MKL*, но с ней тоже загвоздка, реализации под *Delphi* нет.
Вот например, такие простенькие операции с помощью Mathtematica, и уже пробдемы с типом "extended":

```
 1. 0.0000003164955 * 798760 = 0.25280394557999997`  
 2. 0.3875768 - 0.3865584 = 0.0010183999999999749`  
 3. 0.3875768-0.3865587 = 0.0010181000000000218`

1.  0.2528745240765 - 0.25280394557999997 = 0.0000705784965000511
2.  0.3318966 - 0.331826 = 0.00007059999999997624
3.  0.0000705784965000511 / 0.00007059999999997624 = 0.9996954178480858
```

Comment: что-то я в примере ожидал увидеть одинаковые вычисления в двух средах, а числа разные почему то.

Comment: так и про то... Мне нужено добиться одинаковых вычислений...  В Mathematica 5, говорили каким-то образом можно подключаться к библиотеке, но интерфей потерян.

Comment: А можете пояснить каким образом вы вызываете функции/процедуры написанные на Delphi из Mathematica? Возможно, эта задача только для того чтобы ускорить эти самые расчеты? Тогда есть и другие способы ускорения кода. Например CUDALink/OpenCLLink/Compile/WSTPLink/JLink/NetLink. Ссылки на них к сожалению не помещаются в комментарий, но вы легко найдете описание пакетов в документации: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/

Comment: @Kirill Belov. Не много не так пояснил, у меня есть алгоритм написанный на Mathematica, я его перевел на Delphi. Но оказалось, что точность у Mathematica не такая, как в Delphi. Я нашел библиотеку, которая производит все вычиления казалось как нужно, но на n-ом вычислении всеравно при каком-то варианте вычислений, летит ошибка в 18 знаке после точки. **Просто, тогда мне нужен тот вариант библиотеки, которую использует Mathematica** в принципе там действий всего немного "+", "-", "/", "*", "sqrt" и взятие числа в степень

Comment: Вроде как это называется "длинная арифметика" (ищи тут http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/big_numbers.html и http://kladovka.net.ru/index.cgi?pid=dir&rid=8) 

Попробуйте поискать Multiple-Precision Arithmetic на этой странице
http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/Cryptography.htm

Comment: @Konstantin78,0 попробуйте посмотреть вот здесь: https://github.com/benibela/bigdecimalmath

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеки Delphi/Pascal от Вольфганга Эрдхарда http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/misc_en.html#damath  Там можно считать с double double (четырехкратная точность) точностью.